# Unity-How to make multi selection toggle works smart?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

what I'm trying to achieve is I have a list of asset names and multi toggles, the toggle represent the extension of the asset file, if the toggle is checked, find the asset name in the list that not contain this extension.

My code is below, and it actually worked, but it looks stupid, becasue if I add one more toggle, I have to add one more if...else... and the way I use seems just run a lot duplicate code, is there any other way like enum, struct or anything else I can use to make the code more smart?

some more specific problem I am facing:

1. How to use the toggle's label as the key to match asset name?
2. How to make a method to works for all situation that if I have more toggles, because it maybe has three or more key value I have to match.

[image]

if TGA clicked -> bbb.png, ccc.tif, qqq.exr

if TGA and PNG clicked -> ccc.tif, qqq.exr

```
class ShowAssetIds:EditorWindow
{
[MenuItem("Assets/Test")]
static void ShowWindow()
{
    ShowAssetIds window = (ShowAssetIds)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(ShowAssetIds));
    window.Show();
}

bool tga = false;
bool png = false;
List<string> temp = new List<string> { "xxx.tga", "bbb.png", "ccc.tif", "qqq.exr" };
private void OnGUI()
{
    if(GUILayout.Button("MatchString"))
    {
        if(tga & png)
        {
            foreach(var v in temp)
            {
                if(!v.Contains("tga") && !v.Contains("png"))
                {
                    Debug.Log(v);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(tga)
            {
                foreach (var v in temp)
                {
                    if (!v.Contains("tga"))
                    {
                        Debug.Log(v);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var v in temp)
                {
                    if (!v.Contains("png"))
                    {
                        Debug.Log(v);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    tga = EditorGUILayout.ToggleLeft("TGA", tga);
    png = EditorGUILayout.ToggleLeft("PNG", png);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this code a bit more extendible is to create a list of extensions you are looking for.
Check each flag individually, if true add the extension(s) related to that flag.
Then using some Linq or nested loops to find all the matches.

```
using System.Linq;
...

private void OnGUI()
{
    var extensionList = new List<string>();

    if (tga)
    {
        extensionList.Add(".tga");
    }
    if (png)
    {
        extensionList.Add(".png");
    }
    if (jpg)
    {
        extensionList.Add(".jpg");
        extensionList.Add(".jpeg");
    }

    var matches = fileNames
        .Where(fileName => !extensionList
            .Contains(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName))
        );

    foreach (var fileName in matches)
    {
        Debug.Log(fileName);
    }
}
```